# How can I get Android and iPhone IMEI number using Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an Xamarin.forms application, I need to catch the imei number of mobile that is using the application. I am aware of how it is done in Android. But how can I do the same in Xamarin.forms. Please educate me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'Forms-way' of doing this. If you know how on Android you can make use of the [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/). Which means in your shared project create an interface like:

```
public interface IImeiService
{
    string GetImei();
}
```

Now in your Android project implement this interface, so it would be something like:

```
public class ImeiService : IImeiService
{
    public string GetImei()
    {
      // ... Implement your Android code here
    }
}
```

Register your Android code with an attribute on the class **above the namespace**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (ImeiService))]
namespace ImeiApp.Droid {
```

You can now access it, back in your shared code, with:

```
var imei = DependencyService.Get<IImeiService>().GetImei();
```

If you would have an iOS implementation you could repeat the same steps, although you can, of course, use the same interface and call in shared code, so you will only need a iOS specific implementation.

However, since iOS 7 Apple disallows access to this kind of information programmatically, so you cannot get the IMEI number. And if you can, you will use code that will not be allowed through the App Store review process.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain HOW to get the IMEI, but only how to abstract it. Not really an answer to the question.